# How to sum value with condition in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new about SSRS.

I made a report like in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spOit.jpg) and I want to sum values in the red circles into the blue circle.

The value in red circles is obtained summing the columns *Debit* or *Credit* + *Brought Forward*.

It might be Debit or Credit and this is an expression of balance debit:

`=IIF((Fields!BFTotalBalance.Value >0) ,Sum(Fields!Debit.Value, "DepartmentCodeAndDes1")+ Fields!BFTotalBalance.Value,Sum(Fields!Debit.Value, "DepartmentCodeAndDes1"))`

My problem is that I don't know how to sum total, because *Brought Forward Balance* (green cicle on the picture)  can be both (*Debit* or *Credit*).

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. As far as I can tell, if you just sum them the results will be correct. Can you make a copy of your image and show the values you expect to see, I think that will make things clearer.

Comment: @AlanSchofield ok Alan I added the results to a picture on topic
I expect to see the results as the blue circle that from summing of numbers in red circles. I got a problem cause the number on circle greens if they are positive number it will be Debit and if it's negative number it will be Credit
I don't know how to code  an expression

Comment: How are the debit, credit and BF values stored in your dataset? Are they separate fields or all in a single field with some kind of flag for BF values? I think it will be easy once we know the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may need updating once I know more... To complete the answer I would need to know if the debit and credit values are stored in separate columns and if they are always positive or if debits are always stored as positive and credits are always stored negative.

Assuming that

1. All values are signed (+ or -)
2. BF values are signed
3. Debit, credit and BF values are stored in separate columns

Then you can simply do something like.

e.g. Debit:

```
=SUM(Fields!BFTotalBalance.Value + Fields!Debit.Value)
```

If your debit and credits are not signed (they are always positive) then you just need to change the debit calc to be something like.

```
=SUM(Fields!BFTotalBalance.Value + (Fields!Debit.Value * -1))
```

If this expression is placed inside the group (whatever group 10929000 pertains to) then you should get the correct answer. If this doesn't work, let me know how the data is stored (show a small sample from your dataset).

Comment: thanks you for your help but BFTotalBalance.Value(on green circle) that from same parameters.I coded that if BFTotalBalance.Value >0 than show on debit or <0 show on credit. I have no idea how to get BFTotalBalance.Value for an example if i want to sum total of debit columns and get results to box into blue circle so I need to sum BFTotalBalance.Value in debit box with Debit.Value i don't know how to get BFTotalBalance.Value on debit columns cause it from same parameters. sorry if i couldn't use english as well

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data